# Can `git status` report uninitialized submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Another user has added a new git submodule to my project, and pushed it to the remote. In my local repo, I have pulled that remote. I have not run `git submodule update --init --recursive`. The problem is, `git status` shows that everything is kosher:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But the new submodule directory is empty. This is at least very misleading and arguably just plain wrong. My working tree is not up to date.

Is there any git config setting that could make `git status` show me the truth about the uninitialized submodules? I've tried various settings of status.submoduleSummary to no effect.

I'm using git 2.18.0.

Answer (score 1):

[`git submodule status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203):

> Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1. Each SHA-1 will possibly be **prefixed with `-` if the submodule is not initialized**, `+` if the currently checked out submodule commit does not match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and `U` if the submodule has merge conflicts.

(Emphasize mine — phd)

Comment: Doesn't really fix the problem, which is that my users are confused that `git status` (which is all they know) looks clean. Isn't that bad?

Comment: Yes, the fact the users only know `git status` is bad, for sure.